# How do I create a function variable with a variable number of arguments?

Tags: kotlin

I've defined a class that holds reference to a function variable, which I've defined like this:

```
public var funct : (vararg x : View?) -> Unit by Delegates.notNull();
```

When I try to call `funct` with a variable number of arguments like this `funct(v1, v2)` it complains that I have too many variables.

How can I create a variable for a function that takes a variable number of arguments?

Comment: In current kotlin you will see an error on the use of `vararg` in a function type.  It is not allowed (yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options you could pass in an array if you don't know how many arguments there could be

Or you could create overload methods to handle the different amount of arguments, and you would call the function with less arguments from the functions with more arguments.

Comment: But shouldn't this be possible with varargs? Isn't that the point of varargs?

Comment: @nt-complete, no varargs are not supported for function types (yet)

Comment: I ended up writing it using an array, as suggested by Dan so I'll mark this correct.

Comment: @AndreyBreslav, are they supported now?